# How can I use single where clause instead of two identical ones?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, query-optimization

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts p1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, COUNT(amount) cntamt
            FROM posts p2
            WHERE p2.type = 0
               OR p2.amount IN ( :vals2 )
               OR p2.date_time BETWEEN :s2 AND :e2) t
WHERE p1.type = 0
   OR p1.amount IN ( :vals1 )
   OR p1.date_time BETWEEN :s1 AND :e1
ORDER BY p1.id 
LIMIT 0,2
```

As you see, there are two `where` clauses into query above, and both are completely identical. Now I want to know, how can I write the query with single `where` clause?

Comment: They are not the same unless :vals2 is magically the same as :vals1 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pain in MySQL, because it does not support CTEs.  One solution is to use a view.  But that won't work because you have parameters.

Variables are another option

```
SELECT p.*, @cnt as cnt, @amt as cntamt
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             (@cnt := @cnt + 1) as tmp_cnt,
             (@amt := @amt + (case when amount is not null then 1 else 0 end)) as tmp_amt
      FROM posts p CROSS JOIN 
           (SELECT @cnt := 0, @amt := 0) params
      WHERE p.type = 0 OR
            p.amount IN ( :vals2 ) OR
            p.date_time BETWEEN :s2 AND :e2
     ) t
ORDER by p.id;
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, your approach is right and matches expected things. Based on your knowledge, do you recommend I go with which one? variables *(your approach)*? or mine?

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . You might want to measure the performance and choose the one that works fastest.  With an index on `posts(type, amount, datetime)`, they might be quite comparable.

Comment: Just for your information, based on some benchmarks, I figured it out that using variables *(your approach)* is two times faster for a huge dataset.

Comment: May you please tell me what's the reason on using `CROSS JOIN` in your query? It seems redundant to me. Isn't it?

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . A subquery is needed to define the variables.  The `CROSS JOIN` connects that subquery to the rest of the query.

Answer (score 0):

results of COUNT(*) cnt and  COUNT(amount) is same so if you explane what the pupose of this query/what are you trying to get as result can help in better way but for the moment you can use the following:

select * from posts a ,(select count(*),count(column1),column1,column2 from posts group by column1,column2 ) b  where a.column1=b.column1 and a.column2=b.column2 where a.column1=:column1 and a.column2 in (:column2);

Comment: You have to add the filtering (where ) at the end. Again the your query have the performance issue.